# Angular JS - Attach onclick event to all links on a page

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an AngularJS application. A requirement has come up where I have to track whenever a user clicks on an external link (`<a href="http://some-other-site.com/offers">click here for offers</a>`).

Normally in jQuery I would write something like the following:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a[href^="http://"]', function() {
    // perform tracking here
    return true;
});
```

But, I'm trying to avoid using jQuery and do things the Angular way. But what is the best way to handle this in pure Angular? I don't want to resort to putting ng-click's on all the external links, as these will constantly change as new functionality is added.

Comment: This might be helpful https://github.com/incuna/angular-external-link-interceptor

Comment: Do you think using the approach of `handle this in pure Angular` would give you any edge? The challenge looks like something that can be simply resolved without a need for neither AngularJS nor JQuery, so why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm late to the party but I would like to put your question in another perspective:

What is the "angular way" in this context?

I was asking myself the same questions and I came up witch following conclusion:

- "*Angular way*" is not the opposite of "*jQuery way*" simply because
  jQuery is not a framework (jQuery is something every developer
  wonders why it's not the default in every browser)
- I should go the "*Angular way*" always when the task is to change the model data in the application

In your case tracking should be added to external links so I assume no application related data is affected by this change.
In this case I would go with a **solution which is the easiest to maintain** (because we all know that later someone will want either to remove the tracking or add another tracking or both).

1) As already mentioned in the comments, there is pure js way to do it:

```
var externalLinks = document.querySelectorAll('a[href^="http://"]');
for (i = 0; i < externalLinks.length; ++i) {
    var link = externalLinks[i];
    link.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        // track me
    });
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/a7fg217h/1/

2) And one another angular solution:

```
.directive('extLink', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, elem) {
      console.log(elem);
      elem.bind('click', function(e) {
        console.log(e);
      });
    }
  };
})
```

The only difference to the already posted answer is that you use this directive as an attribute:

```
<a ext-link href="http://google.com">Link</a>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/OhPfEzwDK3j4d17O86oo?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I mentioned "Angular way" because lots of tutorials/books recommend avoiding jQuery, or any kind of DOM manipulation, because the Angular way is to rely on data binding to update the DOM.

I did try No. 1) pure JS way, but it doesn't work with dynamically generated links (e.g. in ng-repeat), or links that are in hidden containers (with ng-hide="true").

I never considered using directives though (new to Angular). I'll try that. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can set a directive directly on the **a** tag to ensure all **a** tags within your application get the directive attached to them.

```
.directive('a', function () {
    return {
         restrict: 'E',
         link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
              // your code here
         }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Create an element directive that matches `<a>` elements and add a click handler there.